# Mac Fuse doesn't work

Tags: filesystem

I have installed macfuse and fuse-ext2 multiple times and yet they don't seem to work. I want to be able to mount and edit a Raspberry Pi image file (NTFS) on an SD card. Unfortunately nothing appears of the image file in Finder. What am I doing wrong? One more thing: there's a file that should be edited to be able to write files on the target image. Every tutotiral mentions it yet it cannot be found :

System/Library/Filesystems/fuse-ext2.fs/fuse-ext2.util

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial you've been following? Also which version of the operating system do you have on your Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of MacFUSE have you installed? MacFUSE is no longer maintained and has been replaced by [Fuse for macOS](https://osxfuse.github.io).

The latest version is [3.5.4](https://osxfuse.github.io/2016/12/01/OSXFUSE-3.5.4.html) and it's compatible with Mac OS X 10.5 and above and works on both PowerPC and Intel Macs.

If you require MacFUSE for your system, then there is a [MacFuse google group](http://groups.google.com/group/macfuse) that may be helpful, although I'm not sure how current it is since the onset of Fuse for macOS.

Comment: IIRC, back in the day, Mac Fuse was hard to uninstall completely. Have a good look around your drive to be certain some piece of it isn't still lurking and messing you up. From what I read FUSE for macOS should do the job for you.

Comment: "MacFUSE is no longer maintained and has been replaced by Fuse for macOS"

And yet the website and latest release in 2021 still say "macFUSE"...